# SAS: Left join works for defined numbers but not for a selected list of numbers

Tags: sql, select, join, sas

let's say I have those three tables:

```
data Con1;
input ID Age;
cards;
11 22
23 32
32 3
14 73
;
run;

data Con2;
input ID Age;
cards;
11 22
23 32
32 3
14 73
15 11
7 15
;
run;

data Con3;
input ID Height;
cards;
11 150
23 180
32 181
14 175
15 149
7 159
;
run;
```

Now I want to make a left join between `Con2` and `Con3` but only for the rows that are not in `Con1`.

```
proc sql;
create table works as 
select *
from Con2 where ID not in (select ID from Con1);
run;

proc sql;
create table want as 
select a.*, b.Height from works as a
left join Con3 as b
on a.ID=b.ID;
run;
```

This works fine, but I don't like that fact that I have needed two steps.

So my goal is to get it in only one step that should look somehow like this:

```
proc sql;
create table want_fails as
select
a.*,
b.Height
from Con2 (where=(ID not in (select ID from Con1))) as a
left join Con3 as b
on a.ID=b.ID;
run;
```

And I just don't understand how this resolves in an error, when on the other hand the following statement is working just fine:

```
proc sql;
create table want_works as
select
a.*,
b.Height
from Con2 (where=(ID not in (11 23 32 14))) as a
left join Con3 as b
on a.ID=b.ID;
run;
```

Here is the error:

*ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, -.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored. ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause. ERROR: Invalid value for the WHERE option. ERROR: Some options for file WORK.CON2 were not processed because of errors or warnings noted above.*

So can you please tell me what I'm overlooking?

I only have another workaroud with a `create view` but I prefere the solution from @user2877959.

```
proc sql;
create view test as
select *
from Con2 where ID not in (select ID from Con1);
create table want_works2 as
select
a.*,b.Height from test as a
left join Con3 as b
on a.ID=b.ID;
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample output

Comment: Can you please post the error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a subquery in a `where=` dataset option.

Does this not do what you want?

```
proc sql;
  create table want_works as
  select a.*,
         b.Height
  from Con2 as a
  left join Con3 as b
    on a.ID=b.ID
  where a.ID not in (select ID from Con1);
run;
```

Comment: So there is a difference between `where` and `where=`? Cause in the `where` you - and my workaround - also have a select...

Comment: @Zap . . . Your comment doesn't really make sense.  This query has the correct SQL syntax for what you want to do.

Comment: the `where` in my answer is an SQL where clause where you can have subqueries. The `where=` in your example, between parentheses after the table name, is not SQL. It is a SAS dataset option, same as `keep=`, `drop=`, `rename=`, etc. These do not support SQL queries as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot treat the `where=` dataset option as if it was SQL code. But you could use a sub-query to do the same thing. Your original code (formatted for readability).

```
proc sql;
create table want_fails as
  select a.*
       , b.Height
  from Con2 (where=(ID not in (select ID from Con1))) as a
  left join Con3 as b
    on a.ID=b.ID
;
quit;
```

So instead of trying to use a dataset option just use a sub-query as the A alias.

```
proc sql;
create table want_fails as
  select a.*
       , b.Height
  from (select * from Con2
        where ID not in (select ID from Con1)
       ) as a
  left join Con3 as b
    on a.ID=b.ID
;
quit;
```